# Eggplant wait command only accepts numeric literals as parameters?

Tags: testing, syntax, syntax-error, eggplant

I hate magic numbers in my code, so I want to replace the numeric literals in my wait commands with constant variable names.

For example:

```
wait 60 //How it is now
wait MAX_HALT_TIME  //How I would like it to be
```

However, I get the following syntax error when I do this:

```
FAILURE STInvalidParameters Command wait was called with invalid parameters
```

Is passing the wait function an integer variable even possible in Eggplant?  My declaration of `MAX_HALT_TIME` is correct, to my knowledge so there should be no reason why Eggplant can't treat `MAX_HALT_TIME` as 60 seconds.

```
put 3 into Universal MAX_HALT_TIME
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Eggplant does not evaluate global or universal variables until they are called.  So the wait command automatically saw the variable being passed to the function as a variable and not the numeric literal that it has been equated to.

My solution to this was to have it evaluate to a numeric literal before I passed it to the wait command.  I did this by seperating how I declared my variable (made into two lines instead of one).

```
put 3 into universal MAX_HALT_TIME //Before

universal MAX_HALT_TIME //After
put 3 into MAX_HALT_TIME //After
```